# How to revert special characters when echoing session? PHP

Tags: php, session, special-characters, echo

I have a created a session containing the following data:

**Calle San Andrés**

When I echo back the session the user sees:

**Calle San AndrÃ©s**

In php, how can I convert the echoed code so that it is once again legible by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the encoding used by the client's browser. Probably, you'll just have to set the encoding to UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

use [utf8_encode](http://php.net/utf8_encode) function.
Also make sure your `Content-Type` header has `charset=utf-8`.